# Sed "invalid command code <", when using sed within Applescript

Tags: macos, sed, applescript

I am trying to use Sed to do string replacement within my Applescript.

I am using the following command:

```
set selected_text to do shell script "echo " & "\"" & selected_text & "\"" & " | sed  /'s/<\\(.*\\)>/\\1/'"
```

and I am being met with the following error:

```
The action “Run AppleScript” encountered an error: “sed: 1: "/s/<\(.*\)>/\1/": invalid command code <”
```

Expected input:

```
FirstName LastName <FirstName.LastName@email.com>
```

Expected output:

```
FirstName.LastName@email.com
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Fixed the error: 
Command should have been:

`set selected_text to do shell script "echo " & "\"" & selected_text & "\"" & " | sed  -E 's/.*<(.*)>/\\1/'"`

Answer (score 0):

the better (easier) way is to use `quoted form of` with using `do shell script`. AppleScript escapes the text for you.

The slash in front of the regex was wrong, without it the error disappeared, but there was still an error in your regex. With your sed you want to replace things in your input, so you have to use an input regex matching your whole input. The parentheses then defines the part you want to keep. The first part is to find all items until `<`, the second is the email address you want to keep inside parentheses and finally the closing `>`.

```
set selected_text to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of selected_text & " | sed  's/[^<]*<\\(.*\\)>/\\1/'"
```

Best, Michael / Hamburg